# Trying to load JSErrorCollector on Selenium RemoteWebDriver

Tags: .net, firefox, selenium, remotewebdriver

Im trying to load JSErrorCollector on remote FireFox driver, however, extension doesn't load, but when doing it with local driver, everything works fine.

I placed addon files on remote machine in the same way, as on local one, however, it just doesn't load.

Local setup (Which works):

```
    private IWebDriver CreateLocalFirefoxDriver()
    {
        var seleniumFirefoxCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        var seleniumFirefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

        seleniumFirefoxProfile.AddExtension(@"C:\ReportingQA\JSErrorCollector.xpi");
        seleniumFirefoxProfile.EnableNativeEvents = true;

        seleniumFirefoxCapabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, seleniumFirefoxProfile);

        return new FirefoxDriver(seleniumFirefoxCapabilities);
    }
```

Remote setup (which doesn't work)

```
    private IWebDriver CreateRemoteWebDriver()
    {
        const string seleniumRemoteUrl = "http://***:4444/wd/hub/";

        var seleniumFirefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        seleniumFirefoxProfile.AddExtension(@"C:\ReportingQA\JSErrorCollector.xpi");
        seleniumFirefoxProfile.EnableNativeEvents = true;

        var seleniumFirefoxCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        seleniumFirefoxCapabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, seleniumFirefoxProfile);

        return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(seleniumRemoteUrl), seleniumFirefoxCapabilities);
    }
```

So, what is wrong here?

Comment: The same happens for me in Java. The profile is loaded on remote FF with all properties and configs as defined in DesiredCapabilities, but plugin seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same for java-based tests in selenium 2.43.1 grid. The cause in my case seems to be in the way the extensions are transmitted and written on node's disk. Extensions transmission fail when I run test on windows and grid node is on linux.

In short: extensions file get wrong filenames and are placed in wrong directory in anonymous profile on node. For details see the issue I filed at selenium: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8254

To check how your profile is transmitted, just run the test in debug mode and put a breakpoint after instance of RemoteWebDriver is created. Then ssh to grid node folder: `/tmp/anonymous[hash]webdriver-profile`.

- If your profile files are placed inside `extensions` subdir you probably have some other problem.
- If your profile files are placed directly at `/tmp/anonymous[hash]webdriver-profile` and have 'flattened' filenames like `"extensions\JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com\build.sh"` they won't work and you have the same issue as me.